# how to make drop-down form to remember input in php

Tags: php, forms, input, drop-down-menu

im creating a form which will display data from database, everything is set so far, but i want the form to remember the data in case if user has to write it down again in case of error. I found some similar code concerning only html, but when including php to display a form i find some difficulties for code to remember the last input (current problem is only concerning drop down selection list):

```
$Type = $_POST['petType']; //this should remember last input
<?php
/*upload form and drop-down selection list*/
echo "
<div align='left'>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='ChoosePetCategory.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='500000000' />
<input type='file' name='imagePath' size='600' />

    <select name='petType'>\n
    <option value='-1'>Type:</option>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PetListResult))
    {
    extract($row);
            echo "<option value='$petType' ";
        if($Type == '$petType')
            { 
            echo "? selected='selected'"; 

// i need to make selected true only for last selected option, 
//and redisplay it in the same form again
            }
        echo ">$petType </option>";
    }

echo "</select>
<p><input type='submit' name='Upload' value='Add Pet' />
</form>
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$Type = $_POST['petType']; //this should remember last input
?>
<div align='left'>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='ChoosePetCategory.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='500000000' />
<input type='file' name='imagePath' size='600' />

    <select name='petType'>
        <option value='-1'>Type:</option>
        <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PetListResult))
        { 
            extract($row);
            ?>
            <option value='<?php echo $petType;?>' <?php echo $Type == $petType ? "selected=selected":"";?> ><?php echo $petType;?> </option>
        }
    </select>
<p><input type='submit' name='Upload' value='Add Pet' />
</form>
```

sidenote: make html and php different , it makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing $Type to a string not a variable.

Try

```
if($Type == $petType)
```